# Python Mixed data structure

Tags: python, arrays, json, data-structures

I need some help creating an advanced data structure in Python. I haven't been using the language long, but finding it much harder than PHP when it comes to storing data.

At the end of the day, I want my data like this:

```
data[year][team] = { 'points' : 30, 'yards' : 800 }
```

Basically, I need to be able to retrieve, add, edit, and delete data in a json object by looking up via a year-team pair. Any ideas?

Comment: Just nest dictionaries, these can be converted to and from JSON easily with the module of the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach in my opinion is just using a "dictionary of dictionaries".

`data = {2014: {'Liverpool': {'points': 30, 'yards': 800}}}`

this will allow you to use
`data[2014]['Liverpool']` to get the `{'points': 30, 'yards': 800}` dict.

Adding a year:

`data.update({2015: ....})`

Adding a team to a year:

`data[2014].update({'ManU': ...})`

Updating a year-team combo:

`data[2014]['Liverpool'].update({'points': 33, 'yards': 820})`

etc...

Comment: Thanks Gabriel! And to delete would be: data[2014]['Liverpool'] = None ?

Comment: A better way to do that would be `data[2014]["Liverpool"].clear()` but that would leave the "Liverpool" key in the dictionary, which might be annoying depending on your logic. Instead you could use `data[2014].pop("Liverpool")`, and that way the key is also removed from the 2014 dict.